# What is the difference between echo $_SESSION["column"] and row["column"]?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am new to coding so please bear with me.

My project deals with displaying a lot of user-submitted information, and was wondering if there was substantial difference between both in terms of displaying such information. I understanding that session variables are "temporary" but am confused as to what extent are session variables viable to display information.

If I want users to see each others information, does it matter if I use `$_SESSION["column"]` or `row["column"]` to display the information?

And finally, would sessions be better of use for things like login verification and editing personal information?

Comment: `$_SESSION['column']` is a session variable and a valid PHP variable. `row["column"]` is not a valid variable in PHP.

Comment: `$_SESSION` is a session, `row` is `$row`? Probably a returned column from sql query. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your last question, yes sessions should really be used for login processes and user data changes. That said, user data changes should be immediately followed by a session destroy and some form of validation by your system to ensure the change was legitimate. For instance, an email address change should be followed by validation of the new email at a minimum and if your security will be tighter for compliance you are going to want to validate the legitimacy of the change too, likely by contacting the account holder in some way or another and temporarily holding changes until confirmation is received.

In its most basic description, Sessions are simply a global variable but shouldn't be used as such. New comers seem to get freaked out when they think of sessions like they are some all powerful aspect of PHP. Sure enough they are a good strong feature but not something to fear. Though make sure you know how to use them if it is critical to your security because they do have the capability to trip you up if you use them incorrectly.

There are underlying aspects that you should really get to know about if you intend using them. This doesnt mean you cant use them without it, in a basic site for instance where security really isn't a problem and you just want to pass arbitrary data with no security implications from one page to another then you could use sessions for that if you really must, you would then be treating the session as a global and nothing more you shouldn't do this if you will also be actively using the session for security purposes it should be one or the other.

Of course, it would be a waste of the potential of the session and would add resource bloat because a clean up of the session data would be required. Clean up (garbage collection) would at some point afterwards have to run to remove it from the system.

I do hope this has helped outline the correct usage of sessions for you.

I just want to add one more thing, you can research this and you will find out yourself anyway but i thought i would give you a head starts.

I will point out one more thing briefly. When you set a variable within php it is only alive and available for at the most as long as the script is running, this means that the memory it used gets release at the end of the script or for a specific variable it should be freed as soon as it is no longer needed. With a session this is not the case, its the sole purpose to ensure data stays alive. To remove part of the data from the session you can overwrite the specific part. Something like this will so what you need.

```
$_SESSION['element_to_clear'] = null;
```

This would remove just selected data and leave the session intact for later use.

Comment: This clears up a whole lot, thank you!